# iPhone app crashes only on iOS10 with unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios10

I have an app that is working fine in the app store on iOS 9. On iOS10 betas on device and in Xcode 8 simulator it is crashing when one of the tabs is tapped.

It crashes with the error

[PXPlaceholderView titleLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

The screen (DiaryItemsViewController)is using a .xib file which reference PXPlaceholderView (a UIView sub class) 
[image]
PXPlaceholderView has initWithFrame and initWithCoder methods that dont seem to get called on iOS10

In the primary screen (DiaryItemsViewController) I can set the background on the PXPlaceholderView ok, but cannot set the outlets

```
[self.placeholderView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; //works ok
self.placeholderView.titleLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"No Diary Entries", nil);  //crashes
```

The outlets in the placeholder view appear to be set correctly in the xib and work find in Xcode 7/ios 9

[image]

PXPlaceholderView is an outlet in DiaryItemsViewController

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet PXPlaceholderView *placeholderView;
```

I am a bit stuck as to what has changed in iOS10 to cause this to crash

Comment: Can you show how you load the pxplaceholderview.xib

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 - Ive updated the questions. Hope it is what you are asking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming the Placeholder class fixed this issue

Answer (score 0):

If PXPlaceholderView is a subclass of UIView, then when does it get a titleLabel property?  That's your problem, in that the code is sending a titleLabel message to your instance of PXPlaceholderView, but it doesn't have a property that matches that name.

Comment: Thanks Owen, titleLabel is an IBOutlet configured in PXPlaceholderView.xib. It works fine in iOS9